# Looking for an anthology which includes story about despotic galactic emperor who is sent on a quest to his death with his faithful robot war steed

Tags: story-identification

The story starts with the very long lived emperor (10,000 years) ordering the destruction of a planet on a whim. His court realises he has gone too far and is sent on a quest, but it is a ruse to send him to his death. He meets a mysterious female character who asks him a question, and if he gets it wrong he will die. He finds out this has happened many times to his predecessors for tens of thousands of years.
He was accompanied by a sentient robotic war steed, who has been his friend but is complicit in the ruse.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Any chance you are thinking of the Steel General in Zelazny's "Creatures of Light and Darkness"?  I don't actually remember his supposed origin, but the robotic war steed and the repitition over many lifetimes rings a bell.

Comment: Thanks than, but unfortunately that isn't the book. It was definitely an anthology. I read it in the last 5 years. I don't know when it was published,  but it wasn't an anthology of 'classic' scifi, and I guess it was 21st century

Comment: "The Steel General" was also published as a stand-alone story, *IF* January 1969, and collected in *This Mortal Mountain* (2009).  On the other hand one thing the Steel General was _not_, for all his extended lifespan, was a ruler of any sort.

Answer (score 3):

This  story sounds like "[The Return of the Thin White Duke](https://www.neilgaiman.com/Cool_Stuff/Short_Stories/The_Return_of_the_Thin_White_Duke)" by Neil Gaiman. I read it in ["The Neil Gaiman Reader: Selected Fiction"](https://www.neilgaiman.com/works/Books/The+Neil+Gaiman+Reader/) but it was originally published in 2004 and has been included in [multiple anthologies](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1821727).

Comment: Can you provide a summary for us?